# Fast bitset append?

Tags: c++, performance, bitset

I'm looking for a bitset implementation with fast bit appending, where several bits can be efficiently appended in one go.

e.g.

```
char value = 31;
char n_bits = 5;
fast_bitset bits;
bits.append(value, n_bits);
```

I have so far tried boost::dynamic_bitset and std::vector. Both of which are slow.

---

**Old Post**

I'm using boost::dynamic_bitset to pack some data.

Usually I want to pack ~5 bits at a time which would result in a call like:

```
char value = 31;
char n_bits = 5;
boost::dynamic_bitset<> bits;
for(char n = n_bits-1; n >= 0; --n)
    bits.push_back((value >> n) & 1);
```

However this seems to me quite inefficient, couldn't one add all the bits in one go?

e.g.

```
char value = 31;
char n_bits = 5;
boost::dynamic_bitset<> bits;
bits.append(value, n_bits);
```

I would expect it to do something like:

```
template<typename T>
void append(T value, size_t n_bits)
{
     value <<= sizeof(T) - n_bits; // Make target bits most significant, remove all non-target bits.

     // TODO: Shift bits into proper place and use OR to add all target bits to bitset in one go
}
```

Why doesn't dynamic_bitset have such a function? Would it be possible to implement efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`resize`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#resize) member function.

```
/* Append the lower-order nbits bits from value to set. */
template <typename T>
void append(boost::dynamic_bitset<> &set, T value, size_t nbits)
{
    set.resize(set.size() + nbits);
    for (size_t i=1; i<=nbits; i++) {
        set[set.size() - i] = value & 1;
        value >>= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: But wont that just append either several 0's or 1's to the bitset? e.g. 11111, 00000. How would it work for e.g. 10110?

Comment: @ronag: yes, it will appends either all 0s, or all 1s, but you can reset those later. I'll update the post, give me a sec.

Comment: Sure would have been nice if dynamic_bitset had `.reserve`. :-)

Comment: Beware on the order the bits are being extracted. In this function the LSB is being written to the leftmost array position, i.e. set.size()-1, while on dynamic_bitset the LSB corresponds to the 0th position. The result is that the bits chain is reversed.