# How can i write bits to file as a bit in c++?

Tags: c++, compression, bit, huffman-code

I'm working on Huffman compression and ı need to write a file as a bit and it must include my bits in program.How can ı do this in c++ ?

By the way ı tried every solutions in the web and asked lots of form but ı couldnt fine anything

Comment: Have you tried anything? If not, do it straightforward: write the bits to some data type and then write it to a file. If it doesn't work, consult Stack Overflow.

Comment: @cad No, if it doesn't work, _do some research_. Some _learning_. _Study it for a while_. Consult Stack Overflow as a last resort.

Comment: ı searched 2 days in a row and my english is not too good to understand everything about these.I tried to find something that ı can understand that's why ı ask here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 2):

**Blockwise**: Append your bitsets to a buffer and write bytes, words or even larger portions from the buffer to the file. There is no bitwise file access in C++.

Have a look at [bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754742).

Comment: There is no bitwise file access in modern file systems period